# Visual Basic 2010 - 2D Sprite / PictureBox Animation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, animation, sprite

I am working on creating a 2D game based in Visual Basic 2010. This game requires the animation of 2D objects, or sprites, and I was wondering the best way to do this. Is there a library for this? I have seen some references towards using the XNA Game Studio - does this work for PC? Unfortunately, I cannot use another language with more game development tools - such as C++. This is a constraint of the project that I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better asked on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

DirectX is the obvious native library for windows. and XNA Game Studio does indeed have a PC branch

Answer (score 0):

I recommend SDL .NET as a graphics library for .NET c#.  It's very easy to use and very scalable.

XNA on the other hand requires the XNA framework to be installed on the target computer but you could use it.  You need to register on the XNA website I believe.